# Rubocop Lint/DuplicateMethods -- which duplicate should I keep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, duplicates, rubocop

Rubocop reports:

```
app/models/transformer.rb:8:3: W: Lint/DuplicateMethods: Method Painter#last_color 
  is defined at both app/models/painter.rb:2 and app/models/painter.rb:5.
```

Painter class looks like:

```
class Painter
  attr_accessor :last_color
  alias last_color recent_color

  def last_color
    colors.last
  end
end
```

Which one actually gets used?  The accessor, alias, or method?

Answer (score 0):

The defined method takes priority over the alias and accessor.

The accessor and alias should be deleted, leaving only the method defined in the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to define a public method `last_color` then adding an `attr_accessor` is redundant.

So if you're asking which one would get executed when you run `Painter.new.last_color` then the answer would be your defined method.

You don't need to get rid of the alias (assuming you need it for some reason).